# Impossible connecting to printer in thread

Tags: android, multithreading, networking, printing

My problem is the next: I'm trying to print with my printer via wifi, I can print if I print a unique line. What I need is to create a kind of printer server which is listening requests to print all time in a loop, and through an arraylist with products what I want to print line by line. This is the code that I'm using:

```
for(FinalBarto barto : bartoProducts){
            Product product = barto.getProducts();
            MyPrinter printer = new MyPrinter(product,cxt);
            printer.start();
        }
```

And this is the class MyPrinter:

```
public class MyPrinter extends Thread {

    Product producto;
    Pack pack;
    Context context;
    Socket socket;
    PrintWriter printWriter;

    public MyPrinter(Product producto, Context context){

        this.context = context;
        this.producto = producto;

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            socket = new Socket("192.168.0.254",9100);
            printWriter = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
            printWriter.println("HELLO FROM THE THREAD");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I am setting the IP and the port right there, and I've sent a ping to my printer and this is the correct IP and port. So, I don't know where the problem is, I can't see it.

The error that I obtaing from Android Studio is: 
java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.0.254 (port 9100): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)

Thank you in fordward!

Comment: I assume you've added the internet permission to your manifest?

Comment: Yes, I've added it

Comment: Which protocol are you using to communicate with the printer? If you're using ipp for example you'd need the whole path: e.g. 192.168.0.254/ipp/print with ports most commonly used (although not limited to) 631 and 443